# Android : how to browse page in the same activity à la iPhone

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation

Basically, in Android an Activity represents a screen lifecycle. 
With startActivity(intent) , the app goes on a new Activity.
How to achieve "change page" in the same activity à la iPhone like ? with touch screen in option.

The reason behind this question is
I discovered an Android app Diet2Go. When you pick a diet.
In the tab "My diet" , you can browse your diet page by page.
I know it's in the same activity because when you press on Back button, you return back to your home screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the page in the same Activity is nothing fancy, just call "setContentView()" again when needed, for example. Or if that's an overkill, just add/remove/hide/unhide views on your layout during runtime. Check the methods of the View class for this. You may even animate stuff on the screen, so it looks like a page-flip, or a regular activity-change, whatever.

Also, don't make any assumptions based on the behavior of the back button. You can override that button's behaviour, so it does anything you like, not neccesarily taking the user back to the previous Activity.

Comment: Thanks Scythe, I'd vote if only I had more than 15 points. So you just call "setContentView" but where ? usually it's done in the onCreate method.